# Orthonormality of the mode functions of the Klein-Gordon field in a globally hyperbolic space

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In chapter 3 of "Quantum fields in curved space" of Birrell and Davies, the authors make the following statements.

Consider a real Klein-Gordon field $\phi$ in a globally hyperbolic spacetime, with metric $g_{\mu\nu}$.

The covariant Klein-Gordon equation is

$$(g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}+m^{2})\phi=0$$

Let $\overline V$ be the vector space of all complex-valued solutions to this equation.

Define the following (indefinite) inner product:

$$(\phi_{1},\phi_{2}):=-i\int_{\Sigma} d\Sigma^{\mu}\sqrt -g_{\Sigma} (\phi_{1}\partial_{\nu}\phi_{2}^{\star}-\phi_{2}^{\star}\partial_{\nu}\phi_{1}), \forall \phi_{1},\phi_{2} \in \overline V$$

Now, they say, without proving it, there exists a complete set of solutions $\{u_{i}\}$ of the covariant Klein-Gordon equation, which are orthonormal in the inner product defined, i.e. satisfying

$$(u_{i},u_{j})=\delta_{ij}$$
$$(u_{i}^{\star},u_{j}^{\star})=-\delta_{ij}$$
$$(u_{i},u_{j}^{\star})=0$$

How can I prove the existence of such a basis, satisfying precisely these orthonormality conditions?

Comment: As I commented referring to another post by you, that statement is meaningless without explaining in which topology completeness is understood. BD's textbook is very far from being rigorous and it cannot be used as a guide if you are interested in the mathematical foundation of QFT in CST.

Comment: Have a look at Wald's textbook on qft in cst and balck holes to have some ideas about the modern and rigorous approach. The GNS construction is the key tool here, after having fixed an algebraic quasifree state on the * algebra of the fields or on the corresponding Weyl C* algebra.